# Map Angular subscriptions to execute synchronously

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to map a new array but need to wait until the subscriptions are done before returning the value. What's the correct way to do this? Can I convert these into promises? How?

```
this.firebaseService.getPolls().pipe(first()).subscribe((fetchedPolls:any) => {
      this.polls = fetchedPolls.filter(poll => poll.payload.doc.id == this.pollKey)
      this.pollKey = this.polls[0].payload.doc.id;
      this.firebaseService.getPollVotes(this.pollKey).subscribe((fetchedPollVotes:any) => {
        this.pollVotes = fetchedPollVotes.map((poll:any) => {
          let userKey = poll.payload.doc.get('user');
          let choiceKey = poll.payload.doc.get('choice');
          let username;
          let players;
          this.firebaseService.getUser(userKey).pipe(first()).subscribe((user:any) => {
            username = user.payload.get('username');
          });
          this.firebaseService.getChoice(choiceKey).pipe(first()).subscribe((choice:any) => {
            players = choice.payload.get('players');
          });
          return { username: username, choice: players }
        })
      });
    });
```

**firebase.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map, switchMap, first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {
  // Source: https://github.com/AngularTemplates/angular-firebase-crud/blob/master/src/app/services/firebase.service.ts
  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  getPolls() {
    return this.db.collection('polls', ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')).snapshotChanges();
  }
  getPollVotes(pollKey) {
    return this.db.collection('votes', ref => ref.where('poll', '==', pollKey).orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')).snapshotChanges();
  }
  getUser(userKey) {
    return this.db.collection('users').doc(userKey).snapshotChanges();
  }
  getChoice(choiceKey) {
    return this.db.collection('choices').doc(choiceKey).snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

** UPDATE ***

I tried to following but I'm getting undefined for this.pollVotes. Also, it's important that I keep the subscription alive for this.firebaseService.getPollVotes because I need this to update each time a new vote is created.

```
this.firebaseService.getPolls().pipe(first()).toPromise().then((fetchedPolls:any) => {
  this.polls = fetchedPolls.filter(poll => poll.payload.doc.id == this.pollKey)
  this.pollKey = this.polls[0].payload.doc.id;
}).then(() => {
  this.firebaseService.getPollVotes(this.pollKey).subscribe((fetchedPollVotes:any) => {
    this.pollVotes = fetchedPollVotes.map((poll:any) => {
      let userKey = poll.payload.doc.get('user');
      let choiceKey = poll.payload.doc.get('choice');
      let getUserObservable = this.firebaseService.getUser(userKey).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => of([])));
      let getChoiceObservable = this.firebaseService.getChoice(choiceKey).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => of([])));
      forkJoin([getUserObservable, getChoiceObservable])
         .subscribe((results:any) => {
        // results[0], results[1], result[2], result[3] is our response from services
        console.log(results);
        return { username: results[0].payload.get('username'), choice: results[1].payload.get('players')}
      });
    });
  });
  console.log("results", this.pollVotes);
});
```

}

** ANOTHER UPDATE **

I re-arranged the function a bit and now I am getting two entries in the this.pollVotes array, however the array returns undefined for both values because the subscription on the forkJoin never gets hit. In other words, my two console log statements never log out.

```
this.firebaseService.getPolls().pipe(first()).subscribe((fetchedPolls:any) => {
      this.polls = fetchedPolls.filter(poll => poll.payload.doc.id == this.pollKey)
      this.pollKey = this.polls[0].payload.doc.id;
      this.firebaseService.getPollVotes(this.pollKey).subscribe((fetchedPollVotes:any) => {
        this.pollVotes = fetchedPollVotes.map((poll:any) => {
          let userKey = poll.payload.doc.get('user');
          let choiceKey = poll.payload.doc.get('choice');
          let getUserObservable = this.firebaseService.getUser(userKey).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => of([])));
          let getChoiceObservable = this.firebaseService.getChoice(choiceKey).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => of([])));
          forkJoin([getUserObservable, getChoiceObservable])
             .subscribe((results:any) => {
            // results[0], results[1], result[2], result[3] is our response from services
            console.log("username", results[0].payload.get('username'));
            console.log("players", results[1].payload.get('players'));
            return { username: results[0].payload.get('username'), choice: results[1].payload.get('players')}
          });
        });
        console.log("results", this.pollVotes);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `toPromise()` rxjs operator?

Comment: Use `forkJoin` to emit only when all observables have completed. Please have a look at https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: @Smooth are you still stuck on this question?

Comment: Yes, still stuck. shadowman_93's answer below was a good start but the issue I have now is that the pollKey parameter for the getUserObservable relies on the subscription result from the getPollsObservable. How do I re-arrange this so that I have the pollKey parameter but still wrap them in such a way that I can run logic only after all the subscriptions are done?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [rxjs-forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). Here is tiny example for your case,

```
  let getPollsObservable = this.fireBaseService.getPolls().pipe(catchError((err, caught) => of([])));
  let getPollVotesObservable = this.fireBaseService.getPollVotes(pollKey).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => of([])));
  let getUserObservable = this.fireBaseService.getUser(userKey).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => of([])));
  let getChoiceObservable = this.fireBaseService.getChoice(choiceKey).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => of([])));

  this.getServiceSubscription = forkJoin([getPollsObservable, getPollVotesObservable, getUserObservable, getChoiceObservable])
     .subscribe(results => {
    // results[0], results[1], result[2], result[3] is our response from services
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: The pollKey parameter for the getUserObservable relies on the subscription result from the getPollsObservable. How do I re-arrange this so that I have the pollKey parameter but still wrap them in such a way that I can run logic only after all the subscriptions are done?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getPollData();
  }

  async getPollData() {
    let fetchedPolls = await this.firebaseService
      .getPolls()
      .pipe(first())
      .toPromise();
    this.polls = fetchedPolls.filter(
      poll => poll.payload.doc.id == this.pollKey
    );
    this.pollKey = this.polls[0].payload.doc.id;
    this.getPollVotesData();
  }
  async getPollVotesData() {
    try {
      let getPollVotesProc = this.firebaseService
        .getPollVotes(this.pollKey)
        .pipe(first())
        .toPromise();
      let fetchedPollVotes = await getPollVotesProc;
      fetchedPollVotes.map(async (poll: any) => {
        let userKey = poll.payload.doc.get("user");
        let choiceKey = poll.payload.doc.get("choice");
        let username;
        let players;
        let user = await this.firebaseService
          .getUser(userKey)
          .pipe(first())
          .toPromise();
        let choice = await this.firebaseService
          .getChoice(choiceKey)
          .pipe(first())
          .toPromise();

        players = choice.payload.get("players");
        username = user.payload.get("username");
        this.pollVotes.push({ username: username, choice: players });
        return { username: username, choice: players };
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```