# how to avoid nested subscribe more than two levels

Tags: javascript, angular

I have four subscribes that dependable on each other. I know there are too many answers regarding avoiding nested subscribe. But nobody answers more than two levels.

how to avoid that many nested subscribe

this is my component code

```
if (this.code) {

    this.appService.updateData('Users/clever_token', {code: this.code}).subscribe(data => {

        if (data.detail) {

            this.accessToken = data.detail.access_token;

            this.appService.getCleverData('/v2.1/me', this.accessToken).subscribe(data1 => {

                if (data1.links) {

                    this.userData.user_type = data1.type;

                    this.appService.getCleverData(data1.links[1].uri, this.accessToken).subscribe(data2 => {

                        if (data2.data) {

                            this.userData.name = data2.data.name.first + ' ' + data2.data.name.last;

                            this.userData.clever_id = data2.data.id;

                            this.userData.email = data2.data.email;

                            this.appService.updateData('Users/cleaver_login', this.userData).subscribe(data3 => {

                                if (data3.detail) {

                                    console.log(data3.detail);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

this is service code

```
getCleverData(url, token) {

    let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    })

    return this.http.get(API_PREFIX + url, { headers: reqHeader })
        .pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
                console.log(data);

                if (data) return data;
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}

/** PUT: update a data to the server */
updateData (url, data?) {

    let httpParams = new HttpParams();
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
         httpParams = httpParams.append(key, data[key]);
    });

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + url, httpParams, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
        map((data: any) => {
            if (data.status == 0) {
                this.presentToast(data.message);
            }

            if (data) return data;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

is there any way to avoid that many subscribe. I can't remove any of it because its some of it from our server and others are third party

Comment: look at rxjs operators (mergeMap, zip, forkJoin)

Comment: Take a look to forkJoin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166214/merging-http-observables-using-forkjoin/43166302, this example has just 2 http requests, but you can add more requests.

Comment: I tried. but there is an example of only two levels and I can't use forkJoin because of all API requests dependent one another. I can't call them together

Comment: So you need flatMap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593900/rxjs-one-observable-feeding-into-another. Obviously you have to change your data before send them, but at least you have no nested observer

Comment: You wouldn't nest subscribe, also not for one level

Comment: Check tis out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55701271/5955138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options but as I see you need that structure because you need data from the previous observable so you can use `filter()` and  `switchMap()`.

`filter()` is able to filter out values which do not contain necessary values `switchMap()` - to switch to a new stream.

UPDATE:

There is a refactored version of your code:

```
if (!this.code) {
  return;
}

this.appService.updateData('Users/clever_token', {code: this.code}).pipe(
  filter(data => !!data.detail),
  switchMap(data => {
    this.accessToken = data.detail.access_token;

    return this.appService.getCleverData('/v2.1/me', this.accessToken);
  }),
  filter(data1 => !!data1.links),
  switchMap(data1 => {
    this.userData.user_type = data1.type;

    return this.appService.getCleverData(data1.links[1].uri, this.accessToken);
  }),
  filter(data2 => !!data2.data),
  switchMap(data1 => {
    this.userData.name = data2.data.name.first + ' ' + data2.data.name.last;
    this.userData.clever_id = data2.data.id;
    this.userData.email = data2.data.email;

    return this.appService.updateData('Users/cleaver_login', this.userData);
  }),
).subscribe(data3 => {
  if (data3.detail) {
    console.log(data3.detail);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you create an example at least 3 levels so I can understand it better?